# flutter splash screen jump on android

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to implement my splash screen in flutter. 
as mentioned [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen), I created my splashScreen's theme inside `styles.xml` file and put below code:

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>
```

and in `launch_background` file I put these code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_splash" />
</item>
```

i launched the app, after loading background I faced a 'jump' of a centered logo image.
how can I fix this jump?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anybody having this issue still and the solution(s) over at [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47634#issuecomment-576938513) don't seem to be working:

In your main AndroidManifest.xml file, you probably have these lines given as a solution from the aforementioned GitHub answer:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

You may have placed those lines at the bottom alongside the "flutterEmbedding" meta-data tag. If you did, put them within the `<activity>` tag instead as shown in this example:

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutter_launch_new"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- HERE -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <!-- NOT HERE -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 5):

after found this [solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47634#issuecomment-576938513), I fixed my issues by putting below code inside `LaunchTheme` (at `styles.xml` file):

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the point 3 of [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47634#issuecomment-588233633) resolved my issue :

Just add `windowDisablePreview`

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
         Flutter draws its first frame -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    <!-- Prevent splash screen to jump when transitioning from LaunchTheme to NormalTheme.
         See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47634#issuecomment-588233633-->
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: fixed the bug for me

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still having issue with it: **removing** this line from `styles.xml` fix the problem:

```xml
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

path: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the following line:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

to my styles.xml under the LaunchTheme style, so my styles.xml file is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by now just a workaround and you still have a blank screen between the Launch-Screen and the Waiting Screen:

Your styles.xml file should look like this:

@drawable/launch_background

    true

Will update if their is another better solution.